# Upload in a restricted country is too slow

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ubuntu, filtering

I'm a C programmer and may write programs in Linux area to connect machines over internet. After I examined that speedtest.net can't upload or has a very poor upload speed, I decided to examine a simple TCP socket connection and see whether it's really slow, and found that yes, it's really slow. I've rented a VPS outside of my country. I don't know what's happening by the government in infrastructure and how packets are routed and how they're restricted. Examining what I saw in speedtest.net, again in a simple socket connection proves me that I can't have a chance. When the traffic in shaped so, there's no way. It proves that it's not a restriction on HTTPS or any application layer protocol, when just a simple TCP socket connection also can't succeed to gain reasonable speed. The speed is below 10 kilobytes per second! Damn!

In contrast, after I got disappointed, I examined some barrier breakers like CyberGhost extension for Chrome. I wondered when I saw that it may overcome the barrier by increasing the upload speed to about 200 kilobytes per second! How?! They can't use any method closer to hardware than sockets.

Now I come here to consult with you and see what ideas you may have about it, so that I may write a program or change the written program based on it.

Thank you

Comment: You seems misunderstood Tom. I'm talking about governmental censorship.

Comment: Investigate where the CyberGhost extension is connecting to and see if you can get a similar speed connecting to the same destination, or to nearby destinations. Could be the speed limiting is destination-sensitive.

Comment: Couldn't. It's a sophisticated process. I used Wireshark for this purpose and tried to follow different flows. Between so many packets finding what is really happening is impossible.

Comment: Sure, it is sophisticated, but it is still connecting to specific servers. Those servers may have public things you can use at least for testing speed, such as an HTTP or HTTPS service. If not that, at least try other public servers in the same country.

Comment: With speedtest.net, when I choose servers from within the country, I get normal upload. Can it be a clue?

Comment: What is “normal”? What you normally get in your other tests, 10 KiB/s, or what people normally get with good Internet, 200 KiB/s or more?

Comment: I define a normal upload as the following: consider when I upload a file to my google drive. In this case, no problem exists. I tried ports 80, 443, etc. with my program with no success, while the browser without using extensions may upload normally to google drive. What's the difference?

Comment: Please answer the question with a numeric speed. You wrote “With speedtest.net, when I choose servers from within the country, I get normal upload.” I do not know what speed you mean by “normal upload.” State a number with a unit of measurement, like 10 KiB/s. Do not describe it as “normal” and do not compare it to “upload a file to my google drive.” I do not know what speed you get when you upload a file to your Google drive. Also, what is “within the country”? Is that within your country? Or is that to the country that CyberGhost connects to?

Comment: Ok, now I'll describe with numbers. Let's concentrate on the speedtest.net servers, both with and without CG extension. I'm going to get the output and will report numbers.

Comment: Since my country is Iran and you know that nowadays a serious opposition is against the people, I tried Serverius Connectivity and got 0.07 Mbps upload. When the server is Tehran TCI, the upload is 5.07. When using the extension, the results will be 2.73 and 2.23 respectively. The major difference is that when I don't use the extension the upload is very slow (0.07 which practically means nothing) in compare to 2.73. My question is what does the extension do to overcome the barrier?

Comment: now what's the next step? any idea?

Comment: One possibly relevant (possibly accurate) summary of [How Iran can track and control protesters's phones](https://theintercept.com/2022/10/28/iran-protests-phone-surveillance).  On the whole, I rate it 'plausible', but YMMV.

Comment: First, please update your question by [edit]ing it, information in the comments tends to be unread. -- Second, the suggestion to use Wireshark is still the best idea I see. That's life, supposedly simple question can have answers that mean hard work. You might want to experiment a lot with minimizing the test upload and Wireshark's filters and analyses.

Comment: It seems a good idea to upload the Wireshark pcap file somewhere in Google drive and share it with you if you care to examine it and investigate what's happening inside it. Indeed they're two files, one with CG and one direct.

Comment: Hypothesis: The network limitations are destination-based. Connecting to the Serverius Connectivity servers in the Netherlands or elsewhere gets .07 Mbps. Using CyberGhost connects to CyberGhost servers in Romania and gets 2.2-2.7 Mbps. (The CyberGhost servers then communicate with the ultimate destination, getting whatever speed they get, out of your sight.) Connecting to servers inside your country gets 5 Mbps. If this hypothesis is correct, CyberGhost is not doing anything technological to get better speed, just connecting to servers in a country to which you have better access.

Comment: How can I examine that this hypothesis is true? And if true, how can I overcome?

Comment: Besides, if the government wants to block ips, it probably begin with CG, not my VPS. I didn't install any VPN software like OpenVPN, OpenConnect, ShadowSocks, etc. on my VPS. It's just a git server and I use it for some normal purposes. So it should not have been tracked and limited. While CG servers are probably in the first destinations which the government go to limit.

Comment: Another hypothesis is that my VPS is rented from a company inside my country and their ips can be tracked and limited. The examination of this hypothesis may be this, if you have a server with a static ip, I may give you my program to run on the server and I see whether the upload to the server is also limited. Then we may conclude that the problem is destination ip or not.